# R write elements of nested list to csv

Tags: r, list, nested-lists

I have a list of lists which, in turn, have multiple lists in them due to the structure of some JSON files. Every list has the same number (i.e., 48 lists of 1 list, of 1 list, of 1 list, of 2 lists [where I need the first of the last two]). Now, the issue is, I need to retrieve deeply nested data from all of these lists.

For a reproducible example.

The list structure is roughly as follows (maybe one more level):

```
list1 = list(speech1 = 1, speech2 = 2)
list2 = list(list1, randomvariable="rando")
list3 = list(list2) #container
list4 = list(list3, name="name", stage="stage")
list5 = list(list4) #container
list6 = list(list5, date="date")
listmain1 = list(list6)
listmain2 = list(list6)
listmain3 = list(listmain1, listmain2)
```

The structure should like like so:

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[[1]][[1]][[1]]
[[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]]
[[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]]
[[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]]
[[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]]
[[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]]$speech1
[1] 1

[[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]]$speech2
[1] 2


[[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]]$randomvariable
[1] "rando"



[[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]]$name
[1] "name"

[[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]]$stage
[1] "stage"



[[1]][[1]]$date
[1] "date"



[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[[2]][[1]][[1]]
[[2]][[1]][[1]][[1]]
[[2]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]]
[[2]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]]
[[2]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]]
[[2]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]]$speech1
[1] 1

[[2]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]]$speech2
[1] 2


[[2]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]]$randomvariable
[1] "rando"



[[2]][[1]][[1]][[1]]$name
[1] "name"

[[2]][[1]][[1]][[1]]$stage
[1] "stage"



[[2]][[1]]$date
[1] "date"
```

The end result would look like this:

```
    date  name  speech1  speech2   
1    

2
```

I want to make columns out of the variables which I need and rows out of the lists that I extract them from. In the above example, I would need to retrieve variables speech1, speech2, name, and date from all of the main lists and convert to a simpler dataframe. I'm not quite sure the fastest way to do this and have been knocking my head over with lapply() and purrr for the last couple of days. Ideally, I want to treat the lists as rowIDs with flattened variables in the columns -- but that has also been tricky. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Would the end result be a data frame with 3 rows, each containing the values of the variables you said, where each row name contains the number of the list where the row belongs to?

Comment: The end result would be a data frame with 48 rows (i.e., the original lists, and 3 columns of the variables I require

Comment: Hmm, I'm afraid I don't understand it. Can you edit the question and paste an example of the expected result based on the toy example of your question?

Comment: Apologies try this ^^

Comment: The first row in the data frame belongs to `listmain1` and the second to `listmain2`, right? That is, it would contain the values of date, name, etc... for these lists.

Comment: Yes, exactly. So the rows are the original lists.

Comment: Let me know if my answer is what you're looking for.

Comment: It's very close, I feel. However, given the complicated structure of the data, I'd like to have a solution that uses the index. So, instead of "date" (because there are multiple date variables and R shoots back nothing) I want something like lmain[["X"]][["list6"]][["date]] or something similar but also able to be used for each of the rows.

Comment: Let's make it more concrete. `X = 1`, with your example, you want a function that can extract the date of the sixth list on lmain1?

Comment: Yes, and then, moving forward, one which will extract the date, speech1, and speech2 from all the available lists

Comment: Hmm but I'm getting a bit lost. My answer already returns all the date, speech1, and speech2 from the available lists. Isn't that the desired output?

Comment: Yeah, however, it won't work in the real data for some reason -- my guess is that it has trouble finding the column names, so the return values are NA

Comment: I see. Perhaps the best way is to just post an excerpt of your own data with `dput`. For example, assuming you have a list with 48 elements called `x`, `dput(x[1:10])` would return the first 10 elements of the list. That way we can make sure it fits your example.

Comment: I ended up using Python to do it: 
date_col = []
line_col = []
name_col = []


for entry in obj:
    parts = entry['meetings'][0]['questions'][0]['parts']
    lines = "".join(["".join(part['lines']) for part in parts])
    date = entry['meetings'][0]['date']
    name = entry['meetings'][0]['questions'][0]['name']
    date_col.append(date)
    line_col.append(lines)
    name_col.append(name)

data = {
    'date': date_col,
    'name': name_col,
    'lines': line_col
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.to_feather("language_questions.feather")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looping through each list, flatten it and getting the values, it can be achieved quickly with base R:

```r
# Your data
list1 = list(speech1 = 1, speech2 = 2)
list2 = list(list1, randomvariable="rando")
list3 = list(list2) #container
list4 = list(list3, name="name", stage="stage")
list5 = list(list4) #container
list6 = list(list5, date="date")
listmain1 = list(list6)
listmain2 = list(list6)
listmain3 = list(listmain1, listmain2)

# Loop over each list inside listmain3
flatten_list <- lapply(listmain3, function(x) {
  # Flatten the list and extract the values that 
  # you're interested in
  unlist(x)[c("date", "name", "speech1", "speech2")]
})

# bind each separate listo into a data frame
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, flatten_list))
#>   date name speech1 speech2
#> 1 date name       1       2
#> 2 date name       1       2
```

Unless you want to map the row names to some values in particular from each list, the row names should have the same order as the number of lists. That is, if you run this on 48 nested lists, the row names will go down to `1:48` so no need to use the `row.names` argument.